# Get Azure container location (python)

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I would like to get the location of a given blob storage container. I've instantiated my client:

```
blob_client = BlockBlobService(account_name='account_name', account_key='account_key')
```

and I was hoping I could pull the `get_container_properties()` method from it, but it doesn't return very much information.

```
properties = blob_client.get_container_properties(container_name='container_name')
```

`properties` only contains etagm last_modified, lease, and public_access.

How do I get the location of the container?

Comment: What means the `location` of a `container`? I suppose you want to get the location of your storage account?

Comment: @JoyWang yes , the region of the storage

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Python storage client library to get account region since the client library is for data access purposes. To get account properties, please use Python **Storage Resource Provider** client library: https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/resources/samples/storage-python-manage/

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So my question is...
If I am managing the storage of a different account, using only the container name, account key, and account name, is there a way to derive the location from that information?

Comment: No, there isn't any way to get account region from account name and account key. Please note that the container name has nothing to do with region since it's determined by account.

Answer (score -1):

I think the `location` of the container you mentioned means `storage url` of the container. I searched the Container Class in Blob Storage [Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-java-getting-started/blob/master/src/BlobAdvanced.java) and [.NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer?view=azure-dotnet#properties), they all contain `url` property.

However, in [Python SDK](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.models.html#azure.storage.blob.models.Container), can't find such `url` property in class `azure.storage.blob.models.Container`.

I also check [get container rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/blobcontainers/get),still no such `url` property in response body.

Then I found out that the `URL` is actually stitched in the client code.

[image]

You could use python code to get the url of your container.

```
containerUrl = 'http://'+accountName+'.blob.core.windows.net/'+containerName;
```

Hope it helps you.